# Keep Inactive Checkbox Disable or inactive after Form submit—validation or Repopulating time

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, checkbox

I am using Bootstrap with PHP Codeigniter. I have several checkboxes in my Form. If I click a checkbox, some other checkbox becomes disabled and gray in color. But after Form submit at validation , those disabled or inactive checkboxes become active & lose the gray color. But I do not want this behavior.

**HTML part :**

```
<div class="align">                                    
      <label> <input type="checkbox" size="2" name="M1500" value="01" <?php echo set_checkbox('M1500', '01' ); ?> class="chec1_1500 checker1510"> No </label>     
      <label> <input type="checkbox"   size="2"  name="M1500"  value="02"  <?php echo set_checkbox('M1500', '02' ); ?>   class="chec1_1500 "   > Yes</label>    
      <label> <input type="checkbox"   size="2"  name="M1500"  value="03"  <?php echo set_checkbox('M1500', '03' ); ?>   class="chec1_1500 checker1510"   > Not assessed</label>    
      <label> <input type="checkbox"   size="2"  name="M1500"  value="NA"  <?php echo set_checkbox('M1500', 'NA' ); ?>   class="chec1_1500 checker1510"   > Patient does not have diagnosis of heart failure</label>  
</div>

<div class="align">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="M1510_1"  class="check_1510" Size="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('M1510_1', '1' ); ?>   value="1" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('myForm', 'myCheckbox1',this.checked);"   style="padding-right:20px;" value="1" > No action taken</label>                          
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="M1510_2"  class="check_1510" Size="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('M1510_2', '2' ); ?>   id="myCheckbox1" value="2" > Patient’s Physician</label>                          
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="M1510_3"  class="check_1510" Size="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('M1510_3', '3' ); ?>   id="myCheckbox1" value="3" > Patient  </label> 
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="M1510_4"  class="check_1510" Size="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('M1510_4', '6' ); ?>   id="myCheckbox1" value="6" > Obtained </label> 
    </div>
```

**Java Script :**

```
$('input.chec1_1500').on('change', function() { // 1 checked others disable in same
        $('input.chec1_1500').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
        $('input.chec1_1500').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });    
  $('.checker1510').change(function() { // To disable 1510 
        $('input.check_1510').not(this).prop('checked', false);        
        $('.check_1510').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
    });
```

**Controller :**

```
public function transfer_add(){

            sleep(1);
            $data=array();

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('M1500','','callback_check_1500');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('M1510_1','','');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('M1510_2','','');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('M1510_3','','');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('M1510_4','','');           
           if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){

               $this->load->view('transfer');
           } else {

           $data['M1500 '] =$this->input->post('M1500');
           $data['M1510_1'] =$this->input->post('M1510_1');
           $data['M1510_2'] =$this->input->post('M1510_2');
           $data['M1510_3'] =$this->input->post('M1510_3');
           $data['M1510_4'] =$this->input->post('M1510_4');

 $this->groups_model->add_transfer($data);
            redirect('transfer/index');
           }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide some code, it would be much easier for the people to reconstruct your problem.

Comment: at Codeigniter Form Validaiton i am using  <input type="checkbox" name="M1510_1"  class="check_1510" Size="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('M1510_1', '1' ); ?>   value="1" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('myForm', 'myCheckbox1',this.checked);"   style="padding-right:20px;" value="1" >

Comment: @user3605897 To help you, we need your view (just the checkbox part) and your controller (form validation part) and probably your SetAllCheckBoxes() function. Please use the edit button under your question.

Comment: Thank you for your hope. This is my first post in this site, any mistake do not mind please. I added all as you said. If you need more kindly let me know how can i sent you. Looking forward of your reply.

Comment: Mr. Adrien, once again, thanks for your hope, i would be in waiting.......!!